# How to format java time properly

Tags: java, date

Below is my code for formatting time

```
public class FormatTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FormatTime ft = new FormatTime();
        System.out.println(ft.evaluate("12/01/2014 05:30:15 PM","MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));  
    }

    public String evaluate(String time,String iFormat ,String f) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(f);
        SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(iFormat);

        Date date=inFormat.parse(time);
        String fechaNueva = format.format(date);
        return fechaNueva;
    }

}
```

Out put of this program is as expected that it give **2014-12-01 17:30:15**.
But when I replace hh to HH in iFormat (same as in outputformat) then it give output in 12 out format **2014-12-01 05:30:15**
Same also happens if I convert both in lower case that is hh. Why does this type of inconsistency occur?

Comment: If you replace hh with HH in iFormat, then the time 05:30:15 is read as the 24-hours clock and the PM is ignored...

Comment: @agarwal_achhnera does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat) help you

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was voted down. Perhaps the downvoter could explain his/her reasons?? The code has an error in it, sure, but that's the nature of questions on stackoverflow. An error leads to a question and our collective wisdom helps solve it. Per ardua ad astra. The question may have shown insufficient research effort (which is the case with all questions, or they would be solved before coming to stackoverflow), but it did not show no research effort. I am voting it up, as it is a useful, clear question.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's inconsistent. When you evaluate the time using `HH` it will ignore the `aa` bit, as it's evaluating the input as a 24-hour time, and the `aa` bit makes no sense. However, when you run it with `hh` it will read `05:30:15 PM` as "half five in the afternoon" and writing it will give `2014-12-01 17:30:15`. Reading `05:30:15 PM` as a 24-hour time, will read it as "half five in the morning", throwing the `PM` bit away.

When having both formats with `hh`, you're both reading and writing in 12 hour format. For at to make sense, you would need to add the `aa` bit to the output format as well.

I hope that answers your question in a way that makes sense :)

Comment: you mean to convert time from 12 hour to 24 hour I will have to just give hh to HH

Comment: Yes, that's right. `hh` is "12 hour format" and `HH` is "23 hour format", as explained in the documentation that someone linked to in a comment (which they then deleted): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(            // Parse as a date-time lacking time zone or offset-from-UTC.
    "12/01/2014 05:30:15 PM" ,  // Define a formatting pattern to match input. Case-sensitive formatting code. Use `h` lowercase for 12-hour clock, 0-12. Use uppercase `H` for 24-hour clock, 0-23.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.US )
).format(                       // Generate a String in specific format. Generally better to let java.time localize automatically.
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.US )
)
```

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old date-time classes.

Get the current moment in UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

To see that same moment through the lens of a wall-clock time used by people of a certain region (time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

To generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format on any of these, call `toString`. The java.time classes use standard formats by default when paring/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

If you want other formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` or `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` classes. You can specify a formatting pattern, but easier to let java.time automatically localize.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.FRENCH ; 
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL ).withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

> mercredi 14 février 2018 à 00:59:07 heure normale d’Europe centrale

Or, `Locale.US` & `FormatStyle.SHORT`.

> 2/14/18, 1:01 AM

Your custom format for your input is:

```
String input = "12/01/2014 05:30:15 PM" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu hh:mm:ss a" , Locale.US ) ;
```

That input string lacks any indicator of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it is *not* a moment, *not* a specific point on the timeline. It represents a vague idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours. As such, we parse this input into a `LocalDateTime` lacking any concept of zone/offset.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2014-12-01T17:30:15

Generate a string in that format.

```
String output = ldt.format( f ) ;
```

> 12/01/2014 05:30:15 PM

As others explained, the formatting codes are case-sensitive. If you want 24-hour time, use uppercase `H`. For 12-hour time, use lowercase `h`.

Note that the formatting codes in *java.time* are close to those of the legacy `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly the same. Study the documentation and search Stack Overflow for many examples.

When exchanging date-time values as text, stick with the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism with you vote.