# c# mvc razor datatype.time editorfor not showing stored data in right format on editing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a Time datatype property field in a entity:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime BeginTime { get; set; }
```

In razor view I have this code to creating and editing

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.BeginTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

On creating i can fill this field in right format with a timepicker, for example 01:15 p.m.  and on database it is stored in right datetime format "2017-10-12 13:15:00.000".

But on editing it shows 01:15 a.m. And if i save again the object it modifies field with 01:15 a.m. on database damaging data ("2017-10-12 01:15:00.000").

**I have tried this:**

Set display format of the property in "hh:mm tt"

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm tt}")]
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
public DateTime BeginTime { get; set; }
```

But on editing it takes a empty value for the field like  (--:-- ---) deleting saved data.

Anyone knows how to fix this format issue on editing view?

Comment: I´'m sorry if i had made a lot of gramatical mistakes, i'm Spanish speaker, but i'm doing my best try speaking English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:-

**[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}")]**

For more info:-
hh vs HH :- 
[Difference between java HH:mm and hh:mm on SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat)

Hope it will work.

Comment: Yes, it worked!. Thanks for answering. It displays 1-24 hours format on index but it can be printed from view with @item.BeginTime.Value.ToString("hh:mm tt") . Thanks again.