# Spark sql Unix timestamp returning wrong output

Tags: scala, apache-spark, unix-timestamp

The below query is returning `2017-02-23 00:45:00` instead of `12:45`.

```scala
spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(('2017-02-23 12:45:00')," +
          "'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))").show(false)
```

But the below query is returning expected output

`2017-02-23 13:45:00`

```scala
spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(('2017-02-23 13:45:00')," +
          "'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))").show(false)
```

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should be using capital h** as `HH:mm:ss`

```
spark.sql("select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(('2017-02-23 12:45:00'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) AS date").show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-------------------+
|date               |
+-------------------+
|2017-02-23 12:45:00|
+-------------------+
```

You can get more info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: May I know what is the difference between HhH and hh

Comment: yes sure you can find more detail in the link that I updated in the question or look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341214/difference-between-java-hhmm-and-hhmm-on-simpledateformat